# Design the cache and search feature like hotel booking?

Tags: caching, search, e-commerce, redis, elasticsearch

I need to design the feature like in encommerce(consider hotel booking site) we can enter the keyword/partial-keyword and need to return the relevant results.
For Example :- If site admin or hotel owner needs to add the below hotel details in system , It will be added in cache also(basically it will be write through cache).

Hotel-Name      City        Rating      Rate($)

New River       NewYork     4 Star      500

My question is how to design the below points in the system

1. Do I need to store the Hotel data in cache as key value pair may be using Redis or Memcache ? What will be the key  and value ?
2. If I store it as key value pair, how will I serach using partial keyword(like entering `river newyork` instead of `new river newyork`) which
   can be combination of partial hotel name and city?
3. What can be possible sharded key to distribute the data in cache ?

Consider this system as scalable as `Goibibo` or `Expedia`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to have a search engine. Have you already considered using [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html), instead of implementing such a complex piece of software by yourself?

Comment: Please have a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372478/elastic-seach-for-caching-and-searching-the-product ?/